# Cloudformation BackupRetentionPeriod is not taking any effect on the RDS Aurora cluster

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I set `BackupRetentionPeriod: 15` in my cloudformation template.

```
DatabaseCluster:
DeletionPolicy: Retain
DependsOn:
- MyDBEnhancedMonitoringRole
Properties:
  BackupRetentionPeriod: 15
  DBClusterIdentifier: AppName-Test-database000001
  DBClusterParameterGroupName: default.aurora-postgresql10
  DatabaseName: !Ref 'DBName'
  Engine: aurora-postgresql
  EngineVersion: '10.11'
```

However, it's not taking any effect on the actual instance.

[image]

PS:
I tried setting up the `BackupRetentionPeriod` in DBInstance level and it didn't let me do, since it's a cluster.

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#aws-properties-rds-database-instance-properties): "Amazon Aurora: Not applicable. The retention period for automated backups is managed by the DB cluster."

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari is there any way to increase the backup retention period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's working!

The aws-cli `describe-db-clusters` shows that the change is effective.

```
$ aws rds describe-db-clusters  --db-cluster-identifier appname-test-database000001
{
"DBClusters": [
    {
        "AllocatedStorage": 1,
        "AvailabilityZones": [
            "eu-central-1a",
            "eu-central-1b",
            "eu-central-1c"
        ],
        "BackupRetentionPeriod": 15,
        "DatabaseName": "database000001",
        "DBClusterIdentifier": "appname-test-database000001",
        "DBClusterParameterGroup": "default.aurora-postgresql10",
       .....
       }
```

The confusion was because the UI, which shows the retention period of the `PerformanceInsights` and not the `Backup`